# A curve has the equation $y=2x^2+3x-9$. At point $P$ on the curve, the tangent is parallel to the line $y=4-5x$. Work out the coordinates of $P$.

Tags: quadratics, coordinate-systems, tangent-line

A curve has the equation $y=2x^2+3x-9$. At point $P$ on the curve, the tangent is parallel to the line $y=4-5x$. Work out the coordinates of $P$.

I don't want the answer, I just need help with the workings. My teacher gave me this to do but because I haven't worked with a question like this before I'm not too sure how to do it. The $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of the curve = $4x+3$.

Comment: Parallel lines have the same slope.

Comment: See if the tangent at the given point is parallel to y = 4 - 5x, the slope of the tangent at that point would be equal to the slope of the line y = -5x + 4. And, we know that dy/dx for any curve gives us an equation that results in the slope of the line at that point. Simply equate 4x + 3 to the slope and get a value for x and then input this x into the equation of your curve for y.

Comment: @imranfat I would assume since OP said dy/dx is 4x + 3 they are familiar with the basics.

Comment: @Svee That's a valid point

Comment: Have you found that $ P(2,5)$.

Comment: @Svee thank you lol, i only learnt calculus a few days ago and i am still getting used to it 

Comment: @Smallbrain If you continue like this, you will be Bigbrain.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah one day, one day I'll take the title of bigbrain 

Comment: @Svee worked it out yesterday, forgot to comment, did you get P=(-2,-7)?

Comment: Yep you got it right!